# принцип работы паттерна Singleton

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

есть такой `паттерн`, взятый с этого ресурса:

https://webdevblog.ru/realizaciya-shablona-singleton-v-python/

```py
class Singleton:
    __instance = None
    def __init__(self):
        if not Singleton.__instance:
            print(" __init__ method called..")
        else:
            print("Instance already created:", self.getInstance())
    @classmethod
    def getInstance(cls):
        if not cls.__instance:
            cls.__instance = Singleton()
        return cls.__instance
```

пытаюсь понять принцип работы декоратора `@classmethod` конкретно тут, и правда ли, что `__init__` здесь не создает новый экземпляр, а создается он только вызовом `getInstance`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Патерн синглтон. Смысл его в том что при создании нового объекта Вы получали уже созданный ранее класс. Не новый, а всегда тот же.

Классметод декоратор делает следующее: при вызове на типе он передает тип в метод первым аргументом, а при вызове на инстансе он вытаскивает тип из self и опять же передает его.

Этот декоратор можно описать так

```
def classmethod(method):
    def inner(cls_or_self):
       if type(cls_or_self) == type:
           cls = cls_or_self # Вызов на классе Singleton.getInstance()
       else: 
           cls = type(cls_or_self) # инстранс Singleton().getInstance()
       return method(cls)

    return inner
```

В самой функции получается в первый вызов инстанс, а далее получаем старый.

Мне так удобно хранить пул конектов к базе данных. Дергаешь из любого места и получаешь старый готовый, прогретый пул.

Инстанс новый создает не инит, но если не придираться, то он создается тут новый. Для того чтоб не создавался нужно переопределить метод `__new__()`

```
class Singleton(object):
    __instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        print('__instance', cls.__instance)
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = super(Singleton,cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.__instance

    def __init__(self):
        print('init', id(self))


s = Singleton()
print('s', id(s))
s = Singleton()
print('s', id(s))
```

Вывод

```
__instance None
init 139695236060832
s 139695236060832
__instance <__main__.Singleton object at 0x7f0d54ec16a0>
init 139695236060832
s 139695236060832
```

Тут инит всеравно выполняется. Суть Вашего примера в том чтоб программисты условились получать инстанс только через `getInstance`. У этого подхода есть плюсы - программист не путается в том синглтон это или нет.

Comment: Классметод декоратор делает следующее: при вызове на типе он передает тип в метод первым аргументом, а при вызове на инстансе он вытаскивает тип из self и опять же передает его - можете поподробнее пожалуйста

Comment: @alexander_mqcuin знаком с тем как работают декораторы вцелом? добавил пример реализации

Comment: сильно проще не стало, но спасибо большое!

Comment: может кто-то даст более понятный ответ)
classmethod передает первым аргументом класс, а не сам объект. есть ещё staticmethod который первый аргумент опускает.

Comment: @eri может расскажете?)

Comment: @finally я не знаю как переформулировать ещё

Comment: @eri сам класс? имеется в виду класс как объект, а не экземпляр класса?

Comment: кстати, почитал ваше био, подскажите где взять хорошую инфу по работе сетей, маршрутам, протоколам и тд, никак не могу раз и навсегда разобраться

Comment: @finally я учился этому помогая людям, где-то бесплатно, где-то за деньги...  вот в каждой конкретной мелочи разобрался. основные знания это структура пакетов и прохождение его в ядре системы. из этого можно вывести всю работу сети.

Comment: то есть к литературе не прибегали.. хорошо, будем искать, спасибо!

Comment: @finally читал по диагонали, но к тому времени только ради систематизации знаний. ничего нового не вычитал...